# Is "have a lock on something" same as "having something on lock"?

Tags: idioms, slang, informal-language

And from what I understand they're informal; am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are informal and idiomatic.

The very subtle difference is that "having something on lock" means you have it ready or available in some way whenever you might need it, however unexpectedly.  You might have your attention on something entirely different before needing to use whatever you have on lock, yet it is still available to you.

This subtle connotation regarding timing is less likely to be inferred from "have a lock on something".  It simply means something is readily available to you.

In short, "have a lock on something" indicates availability and readiness, while "having something on lock" additionally indicates something about timing.